How should I correctly use the Response object to return JSON responses in this case? Is there anything else in the code that might be causing issues?
I'm working on a Next.js API route to handle user registration. The code is supposed to check if a username is already taken and return an appropriate response. However, I'm encountering an issue with the Response.json method.
import dbConnect from "@/lib/dbconnect";
import UserModel from "@/model/User";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { sendVerificationEmail } from "@/helpers/sendVerificationEmail";

export async function POST(request: Request){
    await dbConnect();

    try {
        const { username, email, password } = await request.json();

        const existingUserVerifiedByUsername = await UserModel.findOne({
            username,
            isVerfied: true
        });

        if(existingUserVerifiedByUsername){
            return Response.json({
                success: false,
                message: "Username is already taken"
            }, { status: 400 });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error registering user', error);
        return Response.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Error registering user"
        }, { status: 500 });
    }
}

I understand that Response.json might be incorrect and tried using new Response(...), but I'm still not sure if this is the right approach.
The code should return a 400 response if the username is taken and a 500 response if there's an error during registration.

did you tried NextResponse? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response#json

There is a typo isVerfied (should be isVerified I assume, or was this intentional?)
Also try NextResponse.
Note, you are not handling the case where if(existingUserVerifiedByUsername){} condition does not match. Make sure you always send back a response.

Property 'json' does not exist on type '{ new (body?: BodyInit | null | undefined, init?: ResponseInit | undefined): Response; prototype: Response; error(): Response; redirect(url: string | URL, status?: number | undefined): Response; }'    This is the error showing whenever I am returning Response.json why?

All paths should return a response, in your case there's no response if userName is not taken, this should do the work:

export async function POST(request: Request){
    await dbConnect();

    try {
        ...

        if(existingUserVerifiedByUsername){
            return Response.json({
                success: false,
                message: "Username is already taken"
            }, { status: 400 });
        }
        // No user verified by username exists
        // Proceed to create user with mongoose
        const user = await User.create({...});
        return Response.json({
            success: true;
            message: "User created successfully"
        }, {status: 201})

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error registering user', error);
        return Response.json({
            success: false,
            message: "Error registering user"
        }, { status: 500 });
    }
}

